# Bootstrap 3 - Push quadratic blocks

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to build a template but I got problems with the `push pull` class.

**Mobile**:

```
    |------------------|
    |    1    |    2   |
    |------------------|
    |         3        |
    |------------------|

<div class="col-xs-6">1</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">2</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">3</div>
```

**Desktop** *it should look like*

```
|-------|------------|
|   1   |            |
|-------|     3      |
|   2   |            |
|-------|------------|
```

So I have to `push 3` on `lg` by `col-lg-8` and `pull 2` by `col-lg-8`. But Box 2 disappears.

Can someone gimme a hint what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/sUbVdvut9U

**HTML** :
*Always 50%*

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">A</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-center">C</div>
</div>
```

*Style 4/8*   **As you talk about `lg-8`, I think you should prefer this**

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/numuikLwq0

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">A</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 text-center">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks! The last one made it. Totally forgot that nesting is also a way :)

Comment: @Pluutran As you're new on this site, don't forget to accept answer if it works for you please....